# Error during creation of signed apk

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working in an app which is already in live.Now  i have added new features in it.I am trying to create a signed apk after adding the new features but it shows error on the existing modules,But the existing modules work good in live While creating signed apk getting errors from old modules what is the reason for the errors and i Need to know how to create a signed apk for my modified project

```
E:\updated one\Wed Studio\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:842: Error: The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]
            <activity
            ^
E:\updated one\Wed Studio\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:845: Error: The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]
            <activity
            ^

   Explanation for issues of type "WrongManifestParent":
   The <uses-library> element should be defined as a direct child of the
   <application> tag, not the <manifest> tag or an <activity> tag. Similarly,
   a <uses-sdk> tag much be declared at the root level, and so on. This check
   looks for incorrect declaration locations in the manifest, and complains if
   an element is found in the wrong place.
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: its like id names  and minor errors.while running my project int wont show those errors During Creation of signed apk it shows many errors more than 500

Comment: Mention the error you are getting.

Comment: question should be more specific !! did you changed anything in the old modules, any dependency's you removed from the project which is used for old module setup ?

Comment: The main thing when updating the app is to change **versionCode** & **versionName**

Comment: Only God can help you for resolving error! We can also help if you share error details and sufficient details to look into your issue.

Comment: @king of Masses. While compiling my project it shows no error During creation of signed apk it shows error tats my problem.If there is error in my coding it shows during compiling it my project runs good in device but showing errors while creating signed apk

Comment: try disabling lint checking before creating your apk.

Comment: @vimalkumarR To solve issue: Project -> properties, find Android Lint Preferences, in top to right click configure workspace settings... -> unclick "Run full error check when exporting app", apply done.

Comment: Are you by chance using ProGuard?

Comment: is your signed apk getting generated?\

Answer (score 0):

Well, While asking a question in SOF you should be more specific. As per the communication over comments, in your project you don't have any compile time / run time error's in your project but still your unable to export a signed apk for your project.

This is a wired situation discussed here [Android Export aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494035/error-during-creation-of-signed-apk?noredirect=1#comment52848249_32494035)  This may be because of the lint errors in your project you can check in "Problems" view, or the "Lint Warnings" view.

If it is the case, To solve issue:

> Project -> properties,
>
> find Android Lint Preferences, in top to right click configure
>   workspace settings... -> unclick "Run full error check when exporting
>   app", apply done.

or

> Window>Preferences>Android>Lint Error Checking
>
> uncheck Run full error check when exporting app

Comment: Thank you King of Masses.I will try it.Tala vazhga me to thala fan

Comment: What trail @Kind of Masses

Comment: Is it worked for you ? now your able to make a signed apk ?

Comment: not yet I have cleared the errors and tried to create a signed apk but  it shows error in manifest.xml file i have posted it above make read on it king of Masses

Comment: you should place your all activities under the application tag, post your complete manifest file, i vll tell how it vll be